# Jquery Submit To Iframe Not Working in IE9

Tags: jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-9

My Jquery script recently stopped working in IE9. I have a contact form that can upload files using Jquery by submitting to a hidden iframe. The script works in FF, Chrome, IE10, and used to work in IE9 (haven't tested it in 8 or 7). My Iframe submit function is below. The error message I get in IE is "undefined". I am on windows 8 using IE10 in IE9 browser mode. I know there are many similar questions here but none of them hint at a workable solution. Can someone tell me what I need to change to fix this? Thank you!

EDIT: I have found out that Jquery load() does not work with IE for iframe.

```
function mcIframeSubmit(){
    // remove iframe if exists
    $('#mcHiddenIframe').remove();

    // change target attribute on form
    mcForm.attr('target', 'mcHiddenIframe');

    // create and add iframe to page
    $('<iframe />', {
        name: 'mcHiddenIframe',
        id: 'mcHiddenIframe',
        style: 'display:none'
    }).appendTo('body');

    // on response from php file
    $('#mcHiddenIframe').load(function(){
        var mcIframeResponse = $(this).contents().find('.mc1').html();
        var mcIframeError = $(this).contents().find('.mc2').html();

        // reset form
        mcResetForm();

        // hide loading image
        $(mcLoading).hide();

        // scroll to top
        $(mcWrapElement).stop().animate({scrollTop: mcForm.offset().top -60},'slow');

        // display response message
        if (mcIframeError == true) {
            mcResponse(mcIframeResponse, true);
        } else {
            mcResponse(mcIframeResponse, true);

            // redirect on success?
            mcSuccessRedirect();
        }

        // stop iframe load
        $(this).unbind('load');

        // remove form target attribute
        mcForm.removeAttr('target');

        // refresh captcha image
        mcReloadRecaptcha();
    });
}
```